# how to install mssql on to ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, linux

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.2.so.0.1' : file not found.
pugazhl@pugazhl-LIFEBOOK-LH532:~$ # sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA 
pugazhl@pugazhl-LIFEBOOK-LH532:~$ # sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA 
pugazhl@pugazhl-LIFEBOOK-LH532:~$  sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA 
Password: 
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.2.so.0.1' : file not found.
```

Answer (score 1):

To configure SQL Server on Ubuntu, run the following commands in a terminal to install the mssql-server package.

- Import the public repository GPG keys:

> wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo
> apt-key add -

- Register the Microsoft SQL Server Ubuntu repository:

> sudo add-apt-repository "$(wget -qO-
> https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017.list)"

- Run the following commands to install SQL Server:

> sudo apt-get update sudo
>
> apt-get install -y mssql-server

- After the package installation finishes, run mssql-conf setup and follow the prompts to set the SA password and choose your edition.

> sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup

Make sure to specify a strong password for the SA account (Minimum length 8 characters, including uppercase and lowercase letters, base 10 digits and/or non-alphanumeric symbols).

- Once the configuration is done, verify that the service is running:

> systemctl status mssql-server

- If you plan to connect remotely, you might also need to open the SQL Server TCP port (default 1433) on your firewall.

At this point, SQL Server is running on your Ubuntu machine and is ready to use!

You can read [Microsoft Documentation Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-2017)